# Ubuntu 22.04 Random freezes, suspicous kernel logs (kernel: BUG: IRQ stack guard page was hit)

Tags: kernel, 22.04, freeze

I have used Ubuntu 22 on my Acer machine for about 4 months. Just yesterday, I began experiencing random freezes of my system that were so long that I had to reboot by power cycling the laptop. After checking through journalctl, the lines towards the end of the log stood out to me (<REDACTED> replaces my hostname):

```
Mar 14 19:42:34 <REDACTED> kernel: logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C534.0003: device of type eQUAD nano Lite (0x0a) connected on slot 2
Mar 14 19:42:34 <REDACTED> kernel: input: Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023 Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0003/0003:046D:4023.0004/input/input24
Mar 14 19:42:34 <REDACTED> kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:4023.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input1:1
Mar 14 19:42:34 <REDACTED> kernel: input: Logitech Wireless Mouse PID:4038 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0003/0003:046D:4038.0005/input/input29
Mar 14 19:42:34 <REDACTED> kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:4038.0005: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Wireless Mouse PID:4038] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input1:2
Mar 14 19:42:34 <REDACTED> kernel: input: Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0003/0003:046D:4023.0004/input/input33
Mar 14 19:42:34 <REDACTED> kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4023.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input1:1
Mar 14 19:42:34 <REDACTED> kernel: input: Logitech Wireless Mouse PID:4038 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0003/0003:046D:4038.0005/input/input34
Mar 14 19:42:34 <REDACTED> kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4038.0005: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Wireless Mouse PID:4038] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input1:2
Mar 14 19:42:38 <REDACTED> kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4038.0005: HID++ 2.0 device connected.
Mar 14 19:47:30 <REDACTED> kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1678837650.862:89): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/fstab" pid=2378 comm="firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 14 19:47:30 <REDACTED> kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1678837650.986:90): pid=664 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.168" pid=2378 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=5679 peer_label="unconfined"
                                           exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Mar 14 19:47:30 <REDACTED> kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1678837650.986:91): pid=664 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.168" pid=2378 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=5679 peer_label="unconfined"
                                           exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: BUG: IRQ stack guard page was hit at 00000000d765c88f (stack is 000000003b2a86ae..00000000f897f8b7)
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: BUG: #DF stack guard page was hit at 00000000a55b29b0 (stack is 000000005eb8b773..00000000246c01b8)
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: BUG: #DF stack guard page was hit at 00000000a55b29b0 (stack is 000000005eb8b773..00000000246c01b8)
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: BUG: #DF stack guard page was hit at 00000000a55b29b0 (stack is 000000005eb8b773..00000000246c01b8)
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: BUG: #DF stack guard page was hit at 00000000a55b29b0 (stack is 000000005eb8b773..00000000246c01b8)
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: BUG: #DF stack guard page was hit at 00000000a55b29b0 (stack is 000000005eb8b773..00000000246c01b8)
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: BUG: #DF stack guard page was hit at 00000000a55b29b0 (stack is 000000005eb8b773..00000000246c01b8)
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: BUG: #DF stack guard page was hit at 00000000a55b29b0 (stack is 000000005eb8b773..00000000246c01b8)
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: BUG: #DF stack guard page was hit at 00000000a55b29b0 (stack is 000000005eb8b773..00000000246c01b8)
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: BUG: #DF stack guard page was hit at 00000000a55b29b0 (stack is 000000005eb8b773..00000000246c01b8)
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: BUG: #DF stack guard page was hit at 00000000a55b29b0 (stack is 000000005eb8b773..00000000246c01b8)
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: BUG: #DF stack guard page was hit at 00000000a55b29b0 (stack is 000000005eb8b773..00000000246c01b8)
Mar 14 19:50:06 <REDACTED> kernel: BUG: #DF stack guard page was hit at 00000000a55b29b0 (stack is 000000005eb8b773..00000000246c01b8)
```

Another time, I tried viewing the memory usage on the system monitor. When the system froze, the RAM usage was only half its limit, so I don't think I'm running out of RAM.

On one of the boots, I constantly got pop-up windows indicating ibus shutdown unexpectedly and Ubuntu encountered an unexpected error (the "details" drop-down mentioned something about gsd). journalctl revealed:

```
                                           exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Mar 15 15:59:44 <REDACTED> kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1678910384.347:85): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.snap-store" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/discord/discord.desktop" pid=2450 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 15 15:59:44 <REDACTED> kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1678910384.516:86): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snap-store.snap-store" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/discord/discord.desktop" pid=2450 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Mar 15 15:59:45 <REDACTED> kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1678910385.058:87): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.snap-store.snap-store pid=2450 comm="pool-org.gnome." exe="/snap/snap-store/638/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=93 compat=0 ip=0x7fd0dc3a739b code=0x50000
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: gsd-power[2335]: segfault at 7f2f6debf4f0 ip 00007f2f6debf4f0 sp 00007ffe86acf948 error 14 in libgvfscommon.so[7f2f6dee9000+12000]
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f2f6debf4c6.
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: gsd-keyboard[2331]: segfault at 7f01861e84f0 ip 00007f01861e84f0 sp 00007ffde209c7b8 error 14
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f01861e84c6.
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: gsd-media-keys[2333]: segfault at 7fb386c954f0 ip 00007fb386c954f0 sp 00007ffd74af5198 error 14 in libgvfscommon.so[7fb386cbf000+12000]
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7fb386c954c6.
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: evolution-alarm[2382]: segfault at 7f6395ef54f0 ip 00007f6395ef54f0 sp 00007ffedf1cfe08 error 14 in libgvfscommon.so[7f6395f1f000+12000]
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f6395ef54c6.
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: gsd-wacom[2357]: segfault at 7f3fb96b84f0 ip 00007f3fb96b84f0 sp 00007ffc0fe13b38 error 14 in libgvfscommon.so[7f3fb96e2000+12000]
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f3fb96b84c6.
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: gsd-color[2324]: segfault at 7ff889ca74f0 ip 00007ff889ca74f0 sp 00007ffd370da498 error 14 in libgvfscommon.so[7ff889cd1000+12000]
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7ff889ca74c6.
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: gsd-xsettings[2359]: segfault at 7fc0145f14f0 ip 00007fc0145f14f0 sp 00007fff872d1e48 error 14 in libgvfsdbus.so[7fc0145fa000+a000]
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7fc0145f14c6.
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: ibus-extension-[2392]: segfault at 7f3724e724f0 ip 00007f3724e724f0 sp 00007ffd4f3f2598 error 14 in libgvfscommon.so[7f3724e7b000+12000]
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f3724e724c6.
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: ibus-x11[2395]: segfault at 7fb8437504f0 ip 00007fb8437504f0 sp 00007ffd36c4ef88 error 14 in libgvfscommon.so[7fb843775000+12000]
Mar 15 16:00:59 <REDACTED> kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7fb8437504c6.
Mar 15 16:01:29 <REDACTED> kernel: gsd-xsettings[5724]: segfault at 7efd126114f0 ip 00007efd126114f0 sp 00007fff7e4ac158 error 14 in libvorbisfile.so.3.3.8[7efd12620000+2000]
Mar 15 16:01:29 <REDACTED> kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7efd126114c6.
Mar 15 16:01:50 <REDACTED> kernel: gsd-xsettings[5756]: segfault at 7f034301f4f0 ip 00007f034301f4f0 sp 00007fffa7899c88 error 14 in libvorbisfile.so.3.3.8[7f034302e000+2000]
Mar 15 16:01:50 <REDACTED> kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f034301f4c6.
Mar 15 16:01:53 <REDACTED> kernel: gsd-xsettings[5775]: segfault at 7f17181954f0 ip 00007f17181954f0 sp 00007fff19524f98 error 14 in libvorbisfile.so.3.3.8[7f171819f000+2000]
Mar 15 16:01:53 <REDACTED> kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f17181954c6.
Mar 15 16:02:12 <REDACTED> kernel: traps: gmain[2596] trap int3 ip:7fc999327cef sp:7fc98fb26770 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.7200.4[7fc9992e8000+8f000]
```

Would the kernel log explain this behavior? What other steps can I take to troubleshoot? I've seen some people have issues with their NVidia GPU, but my machine doesn't have an NVidia GPU.

The output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux <REDACTED> 5.19.0-35-generic #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 17 15:17:25 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Could be RAM failure. Try using MemTest86 (downloadable from https://www.memtest86.com/) to check your RAM. The longer you run it, the better (preferably do this overnight or longer). If you see RAM errors, that's almost certainly the problem. And even if it's not, it's still a problem that needs to be rectified.

Comment: The error messages ARE ram faults one or more ram chips and or motherboard slots have gone bad. Unless you have recently installed something new that has messed up the machine OS.